# Create media cover flow gallery with server files

Tags: android, audio, video, gallery, android-gallery

I have API which gives all media files i.e Video, Audio and Images urls available on server. Now i have to create custom cover flow **gallery** which will display all **images,audio and videos** available on web server. And click on that respective operation will perform. For example:
Custom gallery will contains all images, audio and videos if user clicks on image it will display image in different window, if clicks on video it will play video file in different window, same case with audio file.

Can you please provide any sample code or link or any idea regarding the same?

If any library is available that would be great.

Comment: Hi Sandy, Did you find a solution to your problem. We are trying to do something similar to what you are doing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of tasks to approach your objective.

First, to take the data you can use a json with data of your gallery, like type (image, video, audio), title, description, url of thumb, url of file, etc.. You can use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the data. To request the thumbs I recommend the [Universal Image Loader for Android](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it even have some gallery demos.

You need to search about [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to start another activities and [adapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to populate your lists.

I don't know what is your knowledge about Android development so I recommend read [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html) tutorials.

Good luck!